# I have not been to somewhere for or in?

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between

> I have not been to Scotland for 2 years.
>
> I have not been to Scotland in 2 years.

Comment: Both are interchangeable. There is no considerable difference.

Comment: You should pay attention to punctuation and formatting. I did that for you. Don't know why you'd want to revert to incorrect punctuation and no formatting. Also I suggest you put in more details, otherwise you run the risk of getting your question closed. Please refer to this [Detail please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been to Scotland for 2 years (BrE)

I have not been to Scotland in 2 years (AmE)

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/british-and-american-english

British and American English

In + period of time after a negative

AmE uses in + a period of time after a negative verb in situations where BrE prefers for:

[AmE]

I haven’t really read anything like that in years. (BrE preferred form: for years)

[AmE]

I haven’t talked to my brother in three years. (BrE preferred form: for three years)

also, I have seen that onto https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-havent-seen-you-in-for-two-years.2777140/

from

e2efour

Senior Member

England (aged 78)

UK English

There is an interesting discussion of the difference between these sentences, based on the US corpus.
See http://learningenglish.voanews.com/content/a-23-a-2003-11-05-3-1-83116507/118317.html.
It says that for is to a large extent BE and in AE. A person's age also has something to do with it.

I would probably say for, but I find in perfectly acceptable. They appear to be interchangeable.